# Combo Box in DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I wanted a combo box in data grid which i added using the following code behind

```
DataColumn dc;
DataGridNS.DataGridTemplateColumn dgc = new DataGridNS.DataGridTemplateColumn();
dgc.Header = dc.ColumnName;
dgc.Width = 100;
dgc.IsReadOnly = true;
DataTemplate dtm = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory outer = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
dtm.VisualTree = outer;
dgc.CellTemplate = dtm;
dtgrdAtlas.Columns.Add(dgc);
```

i want to bind an array to this combo box.
how do i do that.
This code is in a seperate function where i add columns to data grid and my string array is in seperate function/class.

Answer (score 1):

To bind a list to a ComboBox you need to set the `ItemsSource`, or Binding a List to the `ItemsSource`.
Here in this example I set directly the ItemsSource :

```
 MyCombobox.ItemsSource = new List<int> {2, 3, 4 ,5, 6};
```